# Why does the old man in episode 2 describe Oubu as "a part" of the thing that razed Ueno?

Tags: bubuki-buranki

In episode 2, when Oubu ascends to the surface, an old man describes it as "a part" of the thing that razed Ueno.

[image: episode 2, 9:08]

In what sense is Oubu "a part"? Oubu at this time does look slightly different than it did during the incident in Ueno (probably just because Oubu changes shape a bit depending on how powered-up/powered-down it is). Now:

[image: episode 2, 9:24]

And then:

[image: episode 12, 2:39]

But Oubu (unlike Entei) was no more or less "complete" now than in the past, so I'm not sure what the old man means. (Maybe he's just senile?)

Comment: I believe that the japanese original does not convey the meaning of "thing" as a single object.

Comment: Worth noticing the similarities between that old man and the drunk guy in the park in ep 24